# Getting specific incremental key values into an array

Tags: scala, loops, mapping, scala-collections

I have a list which I zipped with indices:

```
val fun_i_map_e = (list.indices zip list).toMap
```

Now, I want to get each key's value incremented by `num:Int` :

```
for (k<-0 until list.length by num)
  for ((k,v) <- fun_i_map_e) {
   bufferArray += v}
```

The idea here is something like this in Java:

```
for (k = 0; k <= list.length; k+= num){
  //increment key k each time and store value into dynamic array }
```

However, I'm getting very random and complete trash output. I would appreciate if someone can help as I'm new in Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. All you need is to shape your `for` function with `yield` as given below

```
val bufferArray = for (k <- 0 until list.length by num) yield fun_i_map_e(k)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = List[Int](5, 6, 7, 8)
val map = list.indices.zip(list).toMap
val num: Int = 15

val incremantedKeys = map.keys.map { k => k  + num }

println("Original keys:")
println(map.keys)
println

println(s"Keys incremented by $num:")
println(incremantedKeys)
```